# Getting "Server Error 500" when using logger.debug in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to find a little bug and need the logger inside one of my models for it. Whenever I use

```
logger.debug "something"
```

inside a model, the message is put in the log but I get a 500 Server Error page. Everything is normal without the logger.debug line.

I set

```
config.log_level = :debug
```

inside the environments/production.rb file and set the correct file permissions for the log but can't seem to find the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the model the `logger` object is not available by default. Use

```
Rails.logger.debug "something"
```

instead...

Comment: Same story, it adds the comment to the log file and throws a 500

    `catchy errorrr message  
    Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 37ms`

Comment: oh my bad! I didn't read the part "the message is put in the log" in your question. Something else might be the issue. is "something" really `"something"` or are you trying to print an object in the log. Can you share your relevant model code?

Comment: The error was caused because I put the logger.debug declaration at the end of the method which messed it's return value. After I moved it and put `Rails.` before it it worked. Thanks!